# How to make looping circle animation?

Tags: animation, loop, looping

Is there an easier way to make a circle looping around without animating its frame? That's means if it can automatically loop around using this circle [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a circle similar to yours and extrude it.

You can add a driver to the Y rotation. See below:

[image]

You can change the value of driver to whatever number you want,

for example: frame / 2   can change to  frame / 1

Comment: How can you show me with video?

Comment: How can I slow down the loop rotation?

Comment: You can change the value of driver to whatever number you want, for example: frame / 2   can change to  frame / 1

Comment: Oh, thanks! I got it.